# How Conditon regex if .. else

Tags: php, regex

**Now REGULAR EXPRESSION**

```
<a\s(class|href|target)=\"(.*)\"\s(class|href|target)=\"(.*)\"\s(class|href|target)=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/g
```

**MATCH THIS LINK**

```
<a href="index.php" target="5454 target 54" class="nav">test</a>
```

But i want to use only one regex using conditions match every url

example:

1. `<a href="index.php">cal</a>`
2. `<a class="xxx" href="index.php">cal</a>`
3. `<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" target="">cal<span>.net</span></a>`

I test this in: https://regex101.com

[**and GET MATHCH INFO LIKE THIS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBhoq.png)

Comment: What in the anchor elements do you want to match?

Comment: If you want to get all links from a document, you may (better) use a DOM parser like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). In any case you need to describe what you want not achieve. Currently you had described what was not working.

Comment: How about this? `(<a\s((class|href|target)=\"(.*)\"\s*)+>(.*)<\/a>)`

Comment: @Richard all in example

Comment: @MariaDeleva I want MATCH INFOMATION (if you use https://regex101.com left hand box like this

MATCH 1
1. [3-8] `class`
2. [10-22] `navbar-brand`
3. [24-28] `href`
4. [30-39] `index.php`
5. [41-47] `target`
6. [49-49] ``
7. [51-71] `nav<span>.net</span>`

Comment: @Richard Use 1 only one regex using conditions match all example

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qY2qE0/2

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nD2pN7/1). However, this is not the right way, using DOM is much cleaner and more readable and maintainable, and is easier to implement actually.

Comment: See @WiktorStribiżew's suggestion, you can access the different match groups by their number: `$1`, for example.

Comment: @splash58 your case possibility , but 2space not match :D

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I want MATCH INFOMATION (if you use regex101.com left hand box like this MATCH 1 1. [3-8] class 2. [10-22] navbar-brand 3. [24-28] href 4. [30-39] index.php 5. [41-47] target 6. [49-49] `` 7. [51-71] nav<span>.net</span>

Comment: only one problem is the spaces. if I put 2 spaces doesn't work @splash58

Comment: Where do you put these spaces?

Comment: @splash58 before > 
and between attribute example class and href

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qY2qE0/3

Comment: @splash58 Loss some MATCH INFOMATION . I want like this https://regex101.com/r/nD2pN7/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew only one problem is the spaces. if I put 2 spaces doesn't work . Problem in  before > and between attribute example class and href

Comment: You are going to have more and more problems with regex, you know? See https://regex101.com/r/nD2pN7/3 - but this is my last contribution here. It must finally make you agree that regex is not the best thing to use for HTML parsing.

Comment: [Obligatory link to the famous StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks you :D

Comment: @splash58 Thanks :)

Comment: @AlohajungVipatchavatee Don't mention it. When you get tired to correct your regex, ask to do it with DOM parser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/iH1cB6/3)):

```
<a
    \s*(?:(class|href|target)=\"(.*?)\")?
    \s*(?:(class|href|target)=\"(.*?)\")?
    \s*(class|href|target)=\"(.*?)\"
    \s*
>
    (.*?)
<\/a>
```

It uses optional non capturing groups: `(?:)?` and lazy quantifiers `*?`. The output is:

```
MATCH 1
5.  [3-7]   `href`
6.  [9-18]  `index.php`
7.  [20-23] `cal`
MATCH 2
1.  [31-36] `class`
2.  [38-41] `xxx`
5.  [43-47] `href`
6.  [49-58] `index.php`
7.  [60-63] `cal`
MATCH 3
1.  [71-76] `class`
2.  [78-90] `navbar-brand`
3.  [92-96] `href`
4.  [98-107]    `index.php`
5.  [109-115]   `target`
6.  [117-117]   ``
7.  [119-139]   `cal<span>.net</span>`
```

Comment: if i 2space before > NOT MATCH

Comment: example : <a href="index.php"(have space)>cal</a>

Comment: Just add `\s*` before `>` @AlohajungVipatchavatee